# Java BigDecimal vs Android BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal, icu

I've faced `java.math.BigDecimal` and `android.icu.math.BigDecimal` as I require to use `BigDecimal` in the project.

I've realized that the Android `BigDecimal` requires API level 24

What is the different between these two classes? I wonder if there is any performance optimization in Android implementation?

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/math/BigDecimal

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya It doesn't mention anything about the difference

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`android.icu.math.BigDecimal` is part of the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) (International Components for Unicode). Since API 24 the Android framework exposes some of the ICU4J classes for you to use. The [Android documentation on Unicode and I18N support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/internationalization) states:

> Some classes in the `java` and `android` packages have equivalents to those
>   found in ICU4J. However, ICU4J often provides broader support for
>   standards and languages.

Don't be confused by the above quote because ICU classes do reside in the `android` package. They were moved to `android.icu` from `com.ibm.icu` in order to avoid conflicts.

Regarding `BigDecimal` in particular: [I found a discussion on the internet](https://sourceforge.net/p/icu/mailman/message/21284480/) which concludes that `BigDecimal` was available in ICU before it was available in Java and is kept in the library for compatibility purposes.

Bottom line: use whatever implementation you like, but `java.math.BigDecimal` is less likely to be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `java.math.BigDecimal` or `android.icu.math.BigDecimal`, there will not be performance difference between both. Because these are basic class, Android `BigDecimal` was re-created with reference of Java `BigDecimal`.

If you ask difference between both, then

- by purpose both are same.
- by code they may differ, can have some less or more methods. So you should read all methods in both classes to find out difference.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal

Android re-create classes to add some feature to existing classes.

Comment: The both reference you've mentioned are the same, I think Android Developer website just copied the main documentation there, I mean https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/math/BigDecimal  which is child of Java `kotlin.Number`

Comment: Is there anything about recreating java classes by Android in that Wikipedia article?

Comment: I highly doubt the court case theory: the class was not "re-created by Android", it is part of the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) which is partly included in Android to [provide broader support for standards and languages](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/internationalization).

Comment: @MarkusPenguin I have edited my answer (removed the wiki link), I think google is separating its classes cause for not to be dependent on Java classes.

Comment: @Mosius no, that's not relevant from your question, I added link to just tell you.

Comment: @Khemraj Any way it should rely on a language, Java or kotlin

Answer (score -5):

I think the TLDR difference is just that `java.math.BigDecimal` is for Java and 
`android.icu.math.BigDecimal` is for Kotlin.

You could read up on their documentation for more detailed differences.

> https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/math/BigDecimal

Comment: I don't think so, it is in android package which is not related to `kotlin`

Comment: If you look at the documentation, you can see it extends kotlin.Number
`kotlin.Any
   ↳ kotlin.Number
        ↳ android.icu.math.BigDecimal` The documentation is also all in kotlin

Comment: I see, but it is not implemented in `kotlin` language any way